# Android live streaming Video - Audio not working

Tags: android, audio, video, rtp

#### The Goal:

Make an android app to stream live video/audio to a PC. The files should not be saved anywhere. Atm im working in java on both ends (android / PC) due to the finds of the libraries libstreamer and vlcj.

#### Overall:

I got the video to work but it doesn't play the audio on the PC.
I tried different encoding for the audio. When trying with AAC - VLC will give an error saying this is an unknown format. Aint getting same error using the format AMRNB, so some audio must be coming through or am i wrong about this?
I have tried several different RTPS testlinks from [G33Ktricks](http://g33ktricks.blogspot.dk/p/the-rtsp-real-time-streaming-protocol.html) Did not manage to find one not working with the PC vlcj.
A logcat for the startup after PC connects to android [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/asjZCPWf)

#### Question:

What am i missing for the audio to work?
If that cannot be answered, is it the android or PC side i should look at to have the most luck finding the missing line?

#### Android:

im using libstreamer and examples from Spydroid to get this working.
The code i startet with is found in the libstreamer pack example 1:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";
private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);

    // Sets the port of the RTSP server to 1234
    Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
    editor.putString(RtspServer.KEY_PORT, String.valueOf(1234));
    editor.commit();

    // Configures the SessionBuilder
    SessionBuilder builder = SessionBuilder.getInstance();

    builder.setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView);
    builder.setPreviewOrientation(90);
    builder.setContext(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_AMRNB);
    builder.setAudioQuality(new AudioQuality(8000,16000));
    builder.setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264);
    builder.setVideoQuality(new VideoQuality(480,320,10,500000));
    builder.setCamera(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
    builder.build();

    // Starts the RTSP server
    this.startService(new Intent(this,RtspServer.class));
}
}
```

#### PC

Using VLCJ for the streaming.
The code i startet with is found in the vlcj-master official pack - Example2:

```
public class Example2
{
private final JFrame                        frame;
private final EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent  mediaPlayerComponent;

public static void main( String[ ] args )
{
    new NativeDiscovery().discover();

    final String mrl = "rtsp://10.251.1.107:1234/trackID=0";

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run( )
        {
            new Example2().start( mrl );
        }
    } );
}

public Example2( )
{
    mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
    frame = new JFrame( "vlcj quickstart" );
    frame.setLocation( 0, 0 );
    frame.setSize( 1400, 800 );
    frame.setContentPane( mediaPlayerComponent );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setVisible( true );
}

private void start( String mrl )
{
    String[] options = {"--ffmpeg-threads=1"};

    EmbeddedMediaPlayer p = mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer();
    p.playMedia( mrl, options );
}
}
```

#### SDP

From the android side:

```
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
Server: MajorKernelPanic RTSP Server
Cseq: 3
Content-Length: 366
Content-Base: 10.251.1.107:1234/
Content-Type: application/sdp
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 10.251.1.107
s=Unnamed
i=N/A
c=IN IP4 10.251.1.125
t=0 0
a=recvonly
m=audio 5004 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 AMR/8000
a=fmtp:96 octet-align=1;
a=control:trackID=0
m=video 5006 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=428015;sprop-parameter-sets=Z0KAFdoHgpoBtChNQA==,aM4G4g==;
a=control:trackID=1
SETUP 10.251.1.107:1234/trackID=0
Requested audio with 16kbps at 8kHz
```

Comment: did you set Destination to the session builder? Did you call session start() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason why...

The following code is from libstreaming net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.SessionBuilder.java

```
if (session.getVideoTrack()!=null) {
        VideoStream video = session.getVideoTrack();
        video.setFlashState(mFlash);
        video.setVideoQuality(mVideoQuality);
        video.setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView);
        video.setPreviewOrientation(mOrientation);
        video.setDestinationPorts(5006);
    }

    if (session.getAudioTrack()!=null) {
        AudioStream audio = session.getAudioTrack();
        audio.setAudioQuality(mAudioQuality);
        audio.setDestinationPorts(5004); //Change this port to anything else fx 5010 worked for me
    }
```